# Make keyword field with multiple text "fields" aggregatable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have a field named "interest" where the user in my application gets information about a specific location and given area of interest (e.g. history, culture, ...).
The field has been created as keyword field, but includes kind of nested fields, although these "fields" are interpreted as text and not as accessible fields themselves.
I would like to make diagrams within the Dashboard, indicating how many users are looking for a specific interest and for which location.
How I can get access to the fields?

Is it possible to realize this with scripted fields? Or do I have to change the mapping of the data and reindex all data?
Currently I don't have Elastic 7.16, so the runtime field functionality is not available. Would it work with runtime fields?

This is how my field "interest" is built:

```
"interest": ["{
    \"type\":\"cult\",
    \"typelabel\":\"Culture\",
    \"placename\":\"80331 Munich\",
    \"geometry\":{
        \"x\":691644.286,
        \"y\":5334746.811,
        \"spatialReference\":{
            \"wkid\":25832,
            \"wkt\":null
        }
    }     
}"]
```

This is how the mapping looks like:

```
"interest" : {
     "type" : "text",
     "fields" : {
       "keyword" : {
         "type" : "keyword",
         "ignore_above" : 256
       }
     },
     "norms" : false
   }
```

Comment: I think you'd need a reindex. Storing JSON in a keyword field is ineffective and usually pointless.

Comment: How do I need to reindex this field to add the "sub-fields"? I added the current mapping of the field as code to my question.

Comment: You can just remove this field from the mapping then ES will infer mapping from the data for you. It's usually decent. Then you can retrieve it via `/INDEX/_mapping` API and modify if needed.